# understanding coefficient values from model with offset

Tags: r, offset, glm, coefficients

I'm using R to perform some statistical analysis and I have some problems in interpreting the model.
consider the following data:

```
df <- data.frame( richness=c(9,13,10,12,11,5,6,8,9,10,10,8, 
                 5,7,6,9,5,6,7,8,4,10,5,8, 
                 4,5,7,5,6,7,4,5,5,6,6,6, 
                 1,0,2,1,4,5,3,2,0,1,4,4),
        condition=c(rep("A",24), rep("B",24)), 
        area = c(12.62, 11.07, 15.72, 15.41, 6.42, 19.13, 17.58, 19.44, 13.55, 18.20, 6.73, 14.79, 5.80, 14.48, 17.89,  7.66, 10.76,  8.90, 8.59, 12.00, 12.93,  7.04, 17.27, 16.34,  9.83,  9.52, 19.75, 10.14, 13.86, 12.31, 16.03, 11.38, 14.17, 15.10, 18.51,  9.21, 20.06, 20.37,  7.97,  7.35,  8.28, 16.65,  6.11, 18.82, 10.45, 16.96, 11.69, 13.24),
        treatment=rep(c(rep("absent",12), rep("present",12)), 2)) 

library(MASS)
nb.fit <- glm.nb( richness ~ condition * treatment, data=df)
exp(coef(nb.fit))
```

by doing the exp(coef(nb.fit)) we can calculate averages from each combination. For the sake of simplicity, let's just use the intercept;
so, the mean richness for A:absent is 9.25 species.
which can be obtained (verified) by:

```
mean(subset(df, condition=="A" & treatment=="absent")$richness)
```

now, consider that we have different sampling sizes, meaning we have different effort. We should (probably must) account for this issue.
So, let's put it as an offset in the model..

```
nb.fit2 <- glm.nb(richness ~ condition * treatment + offset(log(area)),data=df)
```

now look at the model coefficients:

```
exp(coef(nb.fit2))
```

Question 1: is it correct to interpret that the mean richness/area is 0.69 species for A:absent? (in this case 0.69 species per square meter)

Question 2: How is offset computed? for example, I was not able to manually obtain the averages as I did in the first case with
mean(subset(df, condition=="A" & treatment=="absent")$richness)
even when trying to remove the effect of the area with

```
df$richness.area <- df$richness/df$area
mean(subset(df, condition=="A" & treatment=="absent")$richness.area)
```

the average for A:absent is not the same.
I also tried to remove the effect using the residuals of the area and the values were again not the same.

Does anyone know the math involved?

Thanks

Comment: I think this belongs to CrossValidated. See e.g. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11182/when-to-use-an-offset-in-a-poisson-regression for a related question and answer...